# PDF Layout with MigraDoc

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am trying to achieve following matrix kind of layout:

```
TABLE1,1 TABLE1,2
CHART2,1 TABLE2,2
TABLE3 --> occupies whole row 
CHART4 --> ocupies whole row
CHART5,1 CHART5,2
................. List goes on...
```

These components may span over multiple pages. What is the best way to have them side by side and still be able to view them in MigraDoc.

CHART5,1 could be a combination of 4 charts in one cell.

In HTML view I can use following analogy:

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>TABLE1,1</TD> <TD>TABLE1,2 </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>CHART2,1</TD> <TD>TABLE2,2 </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>TABLE3</TD colspan =2>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>CHART4</TD colspan =2> 
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>CHART5,1</TD> <TD>CHART5,2 </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1):

The MigraDoc equivalent for `colspan=2` is `MergeRight=1`. This is a property of the Cell class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I insert a table in a cell then I facing following issue:

If table was supposed to be rendered on two pages, it is restricted to only 1 page. As cell doesn't let the nested table render on to the next page.

Comment: Avoid using nested tables and use smart combinations of `MergeRight` and `MergeDown` instead. Just like you would do it with HTML if nested tables were not available.